# SQL Server- get manager of employee (with exceptions)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am currently stuck with a (for me) quite complicated problem.

I have created following table with cte's:

```
EmployeeID | OrganisationID | Level | Manager1 | Manager2 | Manager3 | Manager4 | Manager5
1          | 1001           | 1     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     
8          | 1011           | 1     | 1        | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     
2          | 1002           | 2     | 1        | 1        | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     
3          | 1002           | 2     | 1        | 1        | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     
4          | 1003           | 4     | 1        | 2        | NULL     | 4        | NULL     
5          | 1004           | 3     | NULL     | NULL     | 2        | NULL     | NULL     
6          | 1005           | 5     | 1        | NULL     | 2        | 6        | 6
7          | 1006           | 5     | NULL     | 7        | 7        | NULL     | NULL
```

What I want to get from this is the manager of each employee, based on their Level. So for someone from `level` 5, I need to get his `Manager5` However, there are some conditions:

- If the `EmployeeID` and the `ManagerX` have the same value, we need to look at `ManagerX-1`. (And if that's the same too, we go one higher again, etc)
- If the ManagerX is empty, we need to look at `ManagerX-1`. (And if that's empty too, we go one higher again, etc)
- For employees from `level` 1, we can just take the manager1

So what I would like as result would be:

```
EmployeeID | RealManager
1          | NULL      
8          | 1         
2          | 1         
3          | 1         
4          | 2         
5          | 2         
6          | 2         
7          | NULL
```

I only got this far

```
SELECT EmployeeID, 
Case    
    when level = 1 then Manager1
    when level = 2 then ISNULL(Manager2,Manager1)
    when level = 3 then ISNULL(Manager3,ISNULL(Manager2,Manager1))
    when level = 4 then ISNULL(Manager4,ISNULL(Manager3,ISNULL(Manager2,Manager1)))
    when level = 5 then ISNULL(Manager5,ISNULL(Manager4,ISNULL(Manager3,ISNULL(Manager2,Manager1))))
    else null
    END as RealManager
FROM cte
```

But this doesn't check the first condition (and it doesn't look quite performant).

Any sugestions or ideas?

Comment: This seems like a bad design to me. What happens when you need to add levels? You will have to add columns as well. You wrote you created this table using ctes, this means that somewhere you have the same data stored otherwise, perhaps in a better way, or even in a way that's going to make it eaiser to get the data you want in this question.
btw, you can replace nested `isnull` functions with a single `coalesce` function: `isnull(a,isnull(b,c)) => coalesce(a,b,c)`.

Comment: You can use coalesce instead of multiple isnull's `coalesce(Manager3,Manager2,Manager1)` - but I agree with @Zohar - you would be better off asking a question quoting the raw data rather than the cte you are trying to use here.

Comment: Putting all 5 managers in the same table is a bad idea. you need to create an extra table Managers with a field Level. Searching for the manager from the level is then super easy and you have no problems when a level needs to be added

Comment: @ZoharPeled @BeanFrog @GuidoG Thanks for the feedback all, I will add the source data of the cte, but that might take a while. I will make sure to keep you updated. Also, the number of levels will not change, and I will replace the `isnull` function

Comment: @DenStudent COALESCE with NULLIF will solve your problem. I had added the query below. Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```sql
--set to 'null' all managers that have same value as employees
;with cte2 (EmployeeID, Level, Manager1, Manager2, Manager3, Manager4, Manager5)
as
(
    select
        EmployeeID
        ,Level
        ,Manager1
        ,case when Manager2 = EmployeeID then null else Manager2 end as Manager2
        ,case when Manager3 = EmployeeID then null else Manager3 end as Manager3
        ,case when Manager4 = EmployeeID then null else Manager4 end as Manager4
        ,case when Manager5 = EmployeeID then null else Manager5 end as Manager5
    from cte
)

--now just select the first non-null manager based on employee's level
select
    EmployeeID
    ,case Level
        when 1 then Manager1
        when 2 then coalesce(Manager2, Manager1)
        when 3 then coalesce(Manager3, Manager2, Manager1)
        when 4 then coalesce(Manager4, Manager3, Manager2, Manager1)
        when 5 then coalesce(Manager5, Manager4, Manager3, Manager2, Manager1)
    end as RealManager
from cte2
```

Comment: I don't see any relation between Managerx ( it's userid) and Level  when you compare them. Change user id start from example 1001 --> 1008 and your query would wrong.

Comment: I haven't made any assumptions on what the `ManagerX` and `OrganisationID` represents. `ManagerX` is treated as just a plain number for comparison with `Level` and `OrganisationID` is just an ID of an organisation, not the user id in the organisation.

Comment: actually just re-read question and `ManagerX` should be used to compare with `EmployeeID`! updated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to make use of below code:

```
    DECLARE @Table TABLE
    (EmployeeID INT,OrganisationID INT,Level INT,Manager1 INT,Manager2 INT,Manager3 INT,Manager4 INT,Manager5 INT)

    INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
    (1,1001,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),    
    (8,1011,1,1   ,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),    
    (2,1002,2,1   ,1   ,NULL,NULL,NULL),    
    (3,1002,2,1   ,1   ,NULL,NULL,NULL),    
    (4,1003,4,1   ,2   ,NULL,4   ,NULL),    
    (5,1004,3,NULL,NULL,2   ,NULL,NULL),    
    (6,1005,5,1   ,NULL,2   ,6   ,6   ),
    (7,1006,5,NULL,7   ,7   ,NULL,NULL)


    SELECT EmployeeID, 
    CASE
        WHEN level = 1 THEN  NULLIF(Manager1,EmployeeID)
        WHEN level = 2 THEN  COALESCE(NULLIF(Manager2,EmployeeID),NULLIF(Manager1,EmployeeID))
        WHEN level = 3 THEN  COALESCE(NULLIF(Manager3,EmployeeID),NULLIF(Manager2,EmployeeID),NULLIF(Manager1,EmployeeID))
        WHEN level = 4 THEN  COALESCE(NULLIF(Manager4,EmployeeID),NULLIF(Manager3,EmployeeID),NULLIF(Manager2,EmployeeID),NULLIF(Manager1,EmployeeID))
        WHEN level = 5 THEN  COALESCE(NULLIF(Manager5,EmployeeID),NULLIF(Manager4,EmployeeID),NULLIF(Manager3,EmployeeID),NULLIF(Manager2,EmployeeID),NULLIF(Manager1,EmployeeID))
        END AS Manager
    FROM @Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Employee AS TABLE
(
   EmployeeID int ,
   OrganisationID int,
   Level int,
   Manager1 int,
   Manager2 int,
   Manager3 int,
   Manager4 int,
   Manager5 int
)

INSERT INTO @Employee VALUES(1          , 1001           , 1     , NULL     , NULL     , NULL     , NULL     , NULL    )
INSERT INTO @Employee VALUES(8          , 1011           , 1     , 1        , NULL     , NULL     , NULL     , NULL     )
INSERT INTO @Employee VALUES(2          , 1002           , 2     , 1        , 1        , NULL     , NULL     , NULL     )
INSERT INTO @Employee VALUES(3          , 1002           , 2     , 1        , 1        , NULL     , NULL     , NULL     )
INSERT INTO @Employee VALUES(4          , 1003           , 4     , 1        , 2        , NULL     , 4        , NULL     )
INSERT INTO @Employee VALUES(5          , 1004           , 3     , NULL     , NULL     , 2        , NULL     , NULL   )
INSERT INTO @Employee VALUES(6          , 1005           , 5     , 1        , NULL     , 2        , 6        , 6)
INSERT INTO @Employee VALUES(7          , 1006           , 5     , NULL     , 7        , 7        , NULL     , NULL   )

;WITH temps AS
(SELECT e.EmployeeID,e.Level, cr.ManagerId, cr.ManagerLevel 
FROM @Employee e
CROSS APPLY
(
   SELECT e.Manager1 AS ManagerId,  1 AS ManagerLevel 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT e.Manager2,  2 AS ManagerLevel 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT e.Manager3,  3 AS ManagerLevel 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT e.Manager4,  4 AS ManagerLevel 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT e.Manager5,  5 AS ManagerLevel 
) AS cr
)
SELECT  e.EmployeeID, t.ManagerId
FROM  @Employee e
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT DISTINCT t.EmployeeID , First_Value(t.ManagerId) OVER (PARTITION BY t.EmployeeID ORDER BY t.ManagerLevel DESC) AS ManagerId
   FROM temps t 
   WHERE t.ManagerLevel <= t.Level AND t.ManagerId IS NOT NULL AND t.ManagerId <> t.EmployeeID
) t ON e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
```